# How to use a JIRA api POST curl in gitlab ci-cd having a body as json

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, jira, jira-rest-api

```
script:
  - echo "Running unit tests... This will take about 60 seconds."
  - apk add curl
  - >
    curl -X POST "https://test.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/" \
    -u "ishaan.kanwar@test.com:${JIRA_TOKEN}"
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{
      "fields": {
        "project": {
          "key": "SNAP"
        },
        "summary": "Testing Gitlab Release",
        "description": "Issue Description",
        "issuetype": {
          "name": "Epic"
        }
      }
    }'
  - echo "Code coverage is 90%"
```

This is giving me an error in my curl request ->
curl: (3) URL rejected: Malformed input to a URL function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
script: |
  echo "Running unit tests... This will take about 60 seconds."
  apk add curl
  curl -X POST "https://test.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/"
    -u "ishaan.kanwar@test.com:${JIRA_TOKEN}"
    -H "Accept: application/json"
    -H "Content-Type: application/json"
    -d '{
      "fields": {
        "project": {
          "key": "SNAP"
        },
        "summary": "Testing Gitlab Release",
        "description": "Issue Description",
        "issuetype": {
          "name": "Epic"
        }
      }
    }'
  echo "Code coverage is 90%"
```

Answer (score 0):

The start of curl has to be a `|` rather than `>`. Idk what a useless fix to this problem it was